# Стать/Становиться в роли простого глагольного сказуемого

Tags: сказуемые, тип-сказуемого

В интернете встретил задачку:

Придумайте предложение где глаголы Стать и Становиться выступают в роли простого глагольного сказуемого.

Эта задачка мне показалась интересной. Поэтому решил поделиться с вами не давая своего ответа или попыток решения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если только в значении "трансформироваться, сделаться, превратиться", то Ваш пример не пойдёт, здесь глагол **стать** вспомогательный:*Я (каков?) словно он. Я (стал каков?)стал словно он.* Составное именное сказуемое.

Согласитесь, это то же самое, что *Он стал умнее. Он стал писателем. Стало (безл.) светло.*

**Возможен пример с глаголом стать в значении "совершиться, оказаться, сделаться"**: *Что такое с ним стало после болезни? На дворе совсем весна стала.*

А в задании, которое Вас заинтересовало, видимо, как раз имелись в виду все значения глагола стать, станет в самостоятельном значении:

Стань сюда. Стань за станок. Стать на путь совершенствования (совершенствоваться). Река стала. Стать на цыпочки.
Что ты станешь делать... Стать на якорь. Ничего с ним не станется.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, это несложно.

Открываете словарь для глагола ***стать***, там указано 12 его значений. [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=стать&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)

И подбираете, какое вам нравится, например: Река стала (замерзла). Он становится у стены и показывает, как делать упражнение.

Comment: Отлично, не думал что глагол стать имеет значение встать (Я встал перед горой = Я стал перед горой). Тогда задача посложнее. Можно использовать глагол стать только в значении трансформироваться.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, если глагол "стать" используется в значении "трансформироваться", то подходит ли такой пример?

> Я стал словно он.